# php simplexml_load_file and null variable

Tags: php, simplexml

I have this very simple php code:

`$xml=simplexml_load_file('abc.xml');
echo $xml;`

It shows only blank page, no characters, nothing... Why? Does simplexml_load_file work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$xml` is an object. You can "visualize" it with

```
var_dump($xml);
```

You should read the examples section on simplexml in the PHP documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php to understand how to display specific nodes information.

If you want to display the content of your xml directly you can do this :

```
//output xml in your response:
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $xml->asXML();
```